# Checking if package installed without errors in R

Tags: r, checksum

**Background to the problem**

I have tried to install the `robustlmm` package in R, but while trying to install it the R session crashed. I followed the on-screen instructions and deleted the `‘/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/00LOCK-robustlmm’` folder.

I then rebooted my computer and installed the package again in R. This time the R quit itself instead of giving me an error message that it crashed. When I booted up R again, I see that the package is listed among my installed packages, and I can run it.

**The actual problem**

Is there a way to check if a package in R has been installed correctly? That is, is there some checksum or similar thing for the package (I am not that computer-savvy so do excuse if the terminology is off), that can be compared to the repository in question? If so, how do I do it?

**Edit**

I uninstalled the package and installed it again. The same problem occured again.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem when installing "robustlmm". What I tried and it did not work:

1. Installing from the CRAN repository in RStudio (which is running on a Debian OS). Both the R session and RStudio have crashed.
2. Installing it from a downloaded tar.gz file in RStudio, which I downloaded from the CRAN page of the package. The same story happened again.
3. Installing in RStudio by donwloading directly from the github page using "devtools". Same result.

The solution: I managed to install the package by running R in a terminal and not through RStudio. The package runs OK now (also in RStudio).